# Force parent div to enlarge itself is child div has overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this structure:

```css
.out {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.in {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
    Sample text
  </div>
</div>
```

When `div.in` has overflow (for example, its content is `SampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletext`), it looks and behaves like this:

```css
.out {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.in {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
    SampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletext
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want it to look like this:

[image: What I want]

How can I do this?

Comment: can you elaborate more
what you want

Comment: @pareshm edited my question

Comment: i have provided css please see if it works

Comment: see my answer below with explanation. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems the div.out is expanding as it suppose to be. But the main issue is text overflowing from `div.in`.

You can either use `word-wrap:break-word` or `overflow`.

Below is a demo with `word-wrap`

```
.in {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/0bukkonv/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you require max-width:300px; because if you remove that then your .in & .out div both will have equal widths irrespective of the content.

You can also set width:100% for the .out div.

In your case:-

```
    .out {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 2px solid green;
      width:100%;
    }

   .in {
     display: inline-block;
     max-width: 300px;
     border: 2px solid red;
     overflow: visible;
   }


   <div class="out">
     <div class="in">
       SampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletext
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that you got answers how to keep the text inside the `300px` width of the `.in` div. but i think you want the text to overflow outside the `.in` div and the `.out` div to wrap that text.

so here is a solution to that :

```js
var text = $(".in").html()
var newtext = $(".in").html("<span class='textwidth'>" + text + "</span>")
var widthText = $(".textwidth").width()
$(".out").width(widthText)
```

```css
.out {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;

}

.in {
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
   SampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletext
  </div>
</div>
```

**A.** first i got the `html` of the `.in` div using the `html()` function **( [info here](http://api.jquery.com/html/) )**  . this gave the result of `SampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletextSampletext`

**B.** second, i changed the `html` found at point A by wrapping it withing a `span` so i can calculate its `width`

**C.** third, in a variable i stocked the `width` of the new `html` element, the `span` which exceeds the `width` of the `.in` div

**D.** lastly i gave the `span` width to the `.out` element

so this solution works regardless of how much text you put inside `.in` div. the `.out` div will always wrap around that text

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the below css and it will work

```
    .out {
        display: inline-block;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 2px solid green;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        overflow:auto;
    }

    .in {
      display: inline-block;
      max-width: 20px;
      max-height:20px;
      border: 2px solid red;

    }
```

Comment: this is not a good answer because you set a fixed width to the `.out` div and if you put more text in the `.in` div it will not work. the width of the `.out` div must be depending on the width of the text inside `.in` div